# Grouping user id columns together with string_agg on PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql

This is my `emails` table

```
create table emails (
  id    bigint not null primary key generated by default as identity,
  name  text not null
);
```

And `contacts` table:

```
create table contacts (
  id        bigint not null primary key generated by default as identity,
  email_id  bigint not null,
  user_id  bigint not null,
  full_name text not null,
  ordering  int  not null
);
```

As you can see I have `user_id` field here. There can be multiple same user ID's on my result so i want to join them using comma `,`

Insert some data to the tables:

```
insert into emails (name) 
values 
  ('dennis1'),
  ('dennis2');

insert into contacts (id, email_id, user_id, full_name, ordering) 
values 
  (5, 1, 1, 'dennis1', 9),
  (6, 2, 1, 'dennis1', 5),
  (7, 2, 1, 'dennis1', 1),
  (8, 1, 3, 'john', 2),
  (9, 2, 4, 'dennis7', 1),
  (10, 2, 4, 'dennis7', 1);
```

My query is:

```
select em.name,
       c.user_ids 
from emails em
  join (       
    select email_id, string_agg(user_id::text, ',' order by ordering desc) as user_ids
    from contacts
    group by email_id
  ) c on c.email_id = em.id
order by em.name;
```

### Actual Result

```
name       user_ids
dennis1    1,3
dennis2    1,1,4,4
```

### Expected Result

```
name       user_ids
dennis1    1,3
dennis2    1,4
```

On my real-world data, I get same user id like 50 times. Instead it should appear 1 time only. In example above, you see user `1` and `4` appears 2 times for `dennis2` user.

How can I unique them?

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e957b52eb46742f3ddea27ec36effb1

P.S: I tried to add `user_id` it to `group by` but this time I get duplicate rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f597ff6bbcfa82f116f8a3efa2244c81)

```
SELECT
    name,
    string_agg(user_id::text, ',' order by ordering desc)
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (em.id, c.user_id)
        *
    FROM emails em
    JOIN contacts c ON c.email_id = em.id
) s
GROUP BY name
```

1. Join the tables
2. `DISTINCT ON` email and the `user_id`, so for every email record, there is no equal users
3. Aggregate